# How to animate from Aligment.Start to Align.End in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

Hopefully this is an easy question, but anyone know how to animate a composable's position based on alignment, for example from Alignment.Start to Alignment.End ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There is not build-in support for this kind of animation, but it is possible to implement it.

If you take a look at `Alignment.kt` file you can see that values like `Start`, `End` are in general implemented based on the concept of *bias* (this concept is also used in e.g. `ConstraintLayout`). Bias **-1** represents **start**, and **1** represents **end** and **0** is **center**.

```
val Start: Alignment.Horizontal = BiasAlignment.Horizontal(-1f)
val CenterHorizontally: Alignment.Horizontal = BiasAlignment.Horizontal(0f)
val End: Alignment.Horizontal = BiasAlignment.Horizontal(1f)
```

Since bias is just a number, we can reduce this problem to simply animating a float value.

Unfortunately the `Alignment` interface is complicated in terms of inheritance and what it exposes as public values (e.g. you cannot read the horizontal bias from values like `Alignment.Start`). That makes it difficult to create a generic solution.

But if you care only about let's say `Alignment.Horizontal` you can create function that animated the horizontal bias and creates `BiasAlignment.Horizontal` object from it:

```
@Composable
private fun animateHorizontalAlignmentAsState(
    targetBiasValue: Float
): State<BiasAlignment.Horizontal> {
    val bias by animateFloatAsState(targetBiasValue)
    return derivedStateOf { BiasAlignment.Horizontal(bias) }
}
```

Here is the usage example, when the horizontal alignment bias is toggled (negated) on every click on a `Column`

```
var horizontalBias by remember { mutableStateOf(-1f) }
val alignment by animateHorizontalAlignmentAsState(horizontalBias)

Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .clickable { horizontalBias *= -1 },
    horizontalAlignment = alignment
) {
    Text("Test")
}
```

[image]

Note that you cannot pass `BiasAlignment.Horizontal` to something that expects `Alignment.Horizontal` and it's not possible to pass it when `Alignment` is expected. You can either change this method to return `BiasAlignment` or create another one for this type of alignment with two bias values.

Answer (score 10):

Building on @maciej-ciemięga's excellent answer, here's a version that allows animating any of the two-dimensional `Alignment` values:

```
@Composable
fun animateAlignmentAsState(
    targetAlignment: Alignment,
): State<Alignment> {
    val biased = targetAlignment as BiasAlignment
    val horizontal by animateFloatAsState(biased.horizontalBias)
    val vertical by animateFloatAsState(biased.verticalBias)
    return derivedStateOf { BiasAlignment(horizontal, vertical) }
}
```

It relies on knowing that these values are all `BiasAlignment`s, but it's nice because then the consumer doesn't need to know about the float values:

```
val a by animateAlignmentAsState(if (foo) Alignment.TopCenter else Alignment.BottomCenter)
```

Answer (score 9):

You can animate between any `Alignment` using `Modifier.onPlaced` and `Modifier.offset` with `Animatable` as shown [in official documents](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/layout/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).onPlaced(kotlin.Function1)).

Result

[image]

Modifier for animation

```
fun Modifier.animatePlacement(): Modifier = composed {
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    var targetOffset by remember { mutableStateOf(IntOffset.Zero) }
    var animatable by remember {
        mutableStateOf<Animatable<IntOffset, AnimationVector2D>?>(null)
    }
    this
        //  onPlaced should be before offset Modifier
        .onPlaced {
            // Calculate the position in the parent layout
            targetOffset = it
                .positionInParent()
                .round()
        }
        .offset {
            // Animate to the new target offset when alignment changes.
            val anim = animatable ?: Animatable(targetOffset, IntOffset.VectorConverter)
                .also {
                    animatable = it
                }


            if (anim.targetValue != targetOffset) {
                scope.launch {
                    anim.animateTo(targetOffset, spring(stiffness = Spring.StiffnessMediumLow))
                }
            }
            // Offset the child in the opposite direction to the targetOffset, and slowly catch
            // up to zero offset via an animation to achieve an overall animated movement.
            animatable?.let { it.value - targetOffset } ?: IntOffset.Zero
        }
}
```

Sample Composable

```
@Composable
fun AnimatedChildAlignment(alignment: Alignment) {
    Box(
        Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(4.dp)
            .border(2.dp, Green400)
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .animatePlacement()
                .align(alignment)
                .size(100.dp)
                .background(Red400)
        )
    }
}
```

Demo

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun AnimatedChildAlignmentTest() {
    var alignment by remember {
        mutableStateOf(Alignment.Center)
    }

    var alignmentValue by remember {
        mutableStateOf(0f)
    }

    alignment = when (alignmentValue.roundToInt()) {
        0 -> Alignment.TopStart
        1 -> Alignment.TopCenter
        2 -> Alignment.TopEnd
        3 -> Alignment.CenterStart
        4 -> Alignment.Center
        5 -> Alignment.CenterEnd
        6 -> Alignment.BottomStart
        7 -> Alignment.BottomCenter
        else -> Alignment.BottomEnd
    }

    val text = when (alignmentValue.roundToInt()) {
        0 -> "Alignment.TopStart"
        1 -> "Alignment.TopCenter"
        2 -> "Alignment.TopEnd"
        3 -> "Alignment.CenterStart"
        4 -> "Alignment.Center"
        5 -> "Alignment.CenterEnd"
        6 -> "Alignment.BottomStart"
        7 -> "Alignment.BottomCenter"
        else -> "Alignment.BottomEnd"
    }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .aspectRatio(1f)
            .padding(10.dp)
    ) {
        
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))
        Text(text = "Alignment: $text", fontSize = 20.sp)
        Slider(
            value = alignmentValue,
            onValueChange = {
                alignmentValue = it
            },
            valueRange = 0f..8f,
            steps = 7
        )
        AnimatedChildAlignment(alignment = alignment)
    }
}
```