# How to animate a center alignment in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-animation, android-jetpack-compose-list

I was playing around with the [Jetpack Compose basic codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-basics), and wanted to add an `Icon` centered in a `Row`, but I'm unable to animate it.

Is it possible to get a smooth animation, so that the icon is always center-aligned vertically while the content is expanding? Right now it just "jumps". Something similar to the `animateContentSize` `modifier`.
Tried [with this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69919858/how-to-animate-from-aligment-start-to-align-end-in-jetpack-compose), but couldn't make it work, since in that example it goes from a start alignment to an end, not center

Video attached to clarify what I mean. Check the star icon on the left of each row
[image]

```
@Composable
fun CardContent(name: String) {
    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(12.dp)
            .animateContentSize(
                animationSpec = spring(
                    dampingRatio = Spring.DampingRatioMediumBouncy,
                    stiffness = Spring.StiffnessLow
                )
            ),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {
        Icon(
            imageVector = Icons.Filled.Star, "",
        )
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .weight(1f)
                .padding(12.dp)
        ) {
            Text(text = "Hello, ")
            Text(
                text = name,
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.h4.copy(
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.ExtraBold
                )
            )
            if (expanded) {
                Text(
                    text = ("Composem ipsum color sit lazy, " +
                            "padding theme elit, sed do bouncy. ").repeat(4),
                )
            }
        }
        IconButton(onClick = { expanded = !expanded }) {
            Icon(
                imageVector = if (expanded) Icons.Filled.ExpandLess else Icons.Filled.ExpandMore,
                contentDescription = if (expanded) {
                    stringResource(R.string.show_less)
                } else {
                    stringResource(R.string.show_more)
                }

            )
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this one?, I modified your code by wrapping the `Text` in an `AnimatedVisibility` scope, though its not exactly like how your sample gif works, but it smoothly animates the `Text` vertically.

```
@Composable
fun CardContent(name: String) {
    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
           .padding(12.dp)
            .animateContentSize(
                animationSpec = spring(
                    dampingRatio = Spring.DampingRatioMediumBouncy,
                    stiffness = Spring.StiffnessLow
                )
            ),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {
        Icon(
            imageVector = Icons.Filled.Star, "",
        )
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .weight(1f)
                .padding(12.dp)
        ) {
            Text(text = "Hello, ")
            Text(
                text = name,
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.h4.copy(
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.ExtraBold
                )
            )
            AnimatedVisibility(
                visible = expanded,
                enter = expandVertically(
                    expandFrom = Alignment.CenterVertically
                ),
                exit = shrinkVertically(
                    shrinkTowards = Alignment.CenterVertically
                ),
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = ("Composem ipsum color sit lazy, " +
                            "padding theme elit, sed do bouncy. ").repeat(4),
                )
            }
        }
        IconButton(onClick = { expanded = !expanded }) {
            Icon(
                imageVector = if (expanded) Icons.Filled.ExpandLess else 
Icons.Filled.ExpandMore,
                contentDescription = null
            )
        }
    }
}
```

With the added animation parameters,

```
enter = expandVertically(
      expandFrom = Alignment.CenterVertically
),
exit = shrinkVertically(
      shrinkTowards = Alignment.CenterVertically
)
```

the animation will be guaranteed to execute in a straight vertical direction.